# Anyway to save Doc ID as a string in Firebase for specific user

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm new to Firebase and wanted to know if there is anyway to access the document id that is created when making a user and save it as a string? For instance, when a user creates their account it saves all their information into Firebase Firestore and saves it with a unique document id. Can you save that document id as a field for that specific user?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question has been asked many times here on SO - it's a good idea to do some research before posting as often times the answer will already be available. When calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` an authResult is returned which contains the user and it's auth data like the `uid`. You can then use it to store additional data in Firestore. [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirestore%5D%5Bflutter%5D+createUserWithEmailAndPassword)

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear. If you want to save a document ID inside a document then It is quite simple. First You'll need to get the document id on the collection reference and then you'll need to set the data on that document id.

```
// Your collection reference
CollectionReference collectionReference=
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your_collection_name');
//Let's get the document ID
String docId = collectionReference.doc().id;
//Now let's save the document id in that document.
collectionReference.doc(docId).set({
    'id': docId, 
  });
```

And if you want to save the user id that is generated upon sign up from firebase authentication then this is how you do it.

```
late String userID;
FirebaseAuth.instance
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: email,
  password: password,
)
    .then((auth) {
  userID = auth.user?.uid;
});
```

And then you can save this userID in your firebase collection.